# what will happen if i delete cache.db or application.db

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nscache

I am noticing all the first xml service requests (i am using sendsynchronous) made getting cached in cache.db in Library Folder.

what are the repercussions of deleting the cache.db file after and before launching the app ?